# PayPal fee value with Direct Payments Pro .NET SDK

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

How does Paypal return the fees for each payment with the Direct Payment Pro .NET SDK?

.NET SDK does not provide a properties to get a fee value. Is it possible to get it for the each successful transaction?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

None of the transaction API responses return a value telling you how much the fee was. If you use the TransactionSearch or GetTransactionDetails API calls you should be able to get that information.

You could also use Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to get all the transaction details sent to you after a payment completes. It's done automatically unlike the API calls I mentioned. There are some .NET IPN code samples:
https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thank you! GetTransactionDetails API is what I really need.